# Error when dynamically obtaining table name TS type

Tags: nestjs

I try to write a method to determine whether the data exists in the data table by passing in parameters and the table name.
But when I use `prisma[table]` a type error occurs.The specific code is as follows.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { ValidationOptions, registerDecorator } from 'class-validator';

export function IsNotExists(
  table: string,
  fields: string[],
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
) {
  return function (object: Record<string, any>, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsNotExists',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [table],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        async validate(value: string) {
          const prisma = new PrismaClient({ log: ['query'] });
          const res = await prisma[table].findFirst({
            where: {
              OR: fields.map(filed => ({ [filed]: value }))
            }
          });
          return !Boolean(res);
        }
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Error message

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PrismaClient<{ log: "query"[]; }, never, DefaultArgs>'. 
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PrismaClient<{ log: "query"[]; }, never, DefaultArgs>'.
```